# PublicKey Authentication for SSH in Pantheon Files

Tags: pantheon-files

Is it possible to connect to a server using the Public Key Authentication for SSH in Pantheon Files? If I select "Connect to Server..." and choose SSH as protocol it only offers me a username and password field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, it's possible by entering `<user>@<host>` into the server field and the password for the private key into the password field.

Comment: But what do you enter to the user name field then and how do you tell it to use the id file?